# If a name in two different columns match extract the value of a third column

Tags: excel

I'm having trouble finding the proper formula for this. I have two columns with stock names where some of them are duplicates. However I want to extract the number i column F into column B if they are duplicates. I tried to do so manually to provide with an example. Anyone knows how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, why did you remove the image from the question, nobody will be able to help you without it as your question is not clear.
Hope this is what you want. Assuming your data is as in the image below, use the following formula

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$E$2:$F$10,2,FALSE),"")
```

or

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F$2:$F$10,MATCH(A2,$E$2:$E$10,0)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it did not post the picture, my bad! https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2uXj.png

Comment: I hope the picture will help explain what I mean!

Comment: Im getting an "#I/T" error with some of the values. What should I change?

Comment: @Skyrup - I've added another formula in answer.